# Numeric pad stops working after turning on keyboard backlight with 'xset led on'

Tags: 16.04, numpad, keyboard-backlight

Numeric pad stops working after turning on keyboard backlight with 'xset led on'... I have also 'tried xset led 3' with the same result.I'm using 16.04 and a Cooler Master Devastator II keyboard.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with my Cooler Master Storm.
I had `xset led 3` set in `~/.bashrc` to turn on the LED's on my keyboard, but also had the non-working Numpad situation.

Although `xset -led` is supposed to turn off all LEDs, I found `xset -led` actually returned Numlock use without actually turning "off" the LED's.

This may not be a 'fix' as much as a workaround; and it must be said that my 16.04 is currently running in VMBox, so this may alter the behaviour as opposed to a bare-metal installation.

May want to have a look at the `xset q`output: Might give some insight into what is and isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

Well at least now I have my numeric pad working... I went to Universal Access and turned off the Mouse Cursor movement.